# Predict the result after passing the pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1023;
    char *p = (char *)&x;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
}
```

The result is: -1 3 0 0

I have imagined:

int x = 1023 (4 bytes):

```
                m    m+1  m+2  m+3
        -+----+----+----+----+----+----+-
         |    | 255| 3  | 0  | 0  |    | 
        -+----+----+----+----+----+----+-
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

cast to char pointer:

```
            m    
    -+----+----+----+----+----+----+-
     |    | 255| 3  | 0  | 0  |    | 
    -+----+----+----+----+----+----+-
          ~~~~~~
```

Why is the result -1 3 0 0? Or where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use `unsigned char` and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: @Barmar How? `char*` is allowed to alias any type, and promotes to `int` in `prtintf()` doesn't it? It could be UB `if sizeof(int) < 4` I suppose.

Comment: You're assuming `char` is an `unsigned` type.   Actually, it is implementation-defined whether it is `signed` or `unsigned` and your implementation uses a `signed` type.     Use `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it undefined behavior, it is often implementation dependent and reproducible **on a specific platform**. In your case the type `char` seems to be `signed char`. Try `unsigned char *`. Read about byte order (endianness) and implementation dependent size of data types.

Comment: @Peter Standard conversions are done when calling variadic functions, so `char` is converted to `int`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think using `char *` is undefined behavior, more like the sign bit just happening to be set. This seems like 2's complement, so 255 == 11111111 == -1 as a signed `char`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 You're right, it's implementation-defined, since the result depends on how integers are represented, including things like endianness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` can be either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, it's implementation-dependent. Your implementation uses `signed char`. The values range from `-128` to `127`, `255` is not a possible value. That byte representation corresponds to `-1`.

Change your pointer declaration to

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&x;
```

and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: `0xFF` is `-0` in 1's complement. :-)